# How to remove emojis from panda DataFrame column? Works on individual string but not whole column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove emojis from column in pandas dataframe. Using this code:

```
def remove_emoji(string):
   emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
                       u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
                       u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
                       u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
                       u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                       u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
                       u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
                       "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
return emoji_pattern.sub(r'', string)
def decontracted(phrase):
   # specific
   phrase = phrase.rstrip()
   phrase = ' '.join(phrase.split())
   phrase = re.sub(r'\w+:\/{2}[\d\w-]+(\.[\d\w-]+)*(?:(?:\/[^\s/]*))*', '', phrase)
   phrase = re.sub('@[\w]+','',phrase)
   phrase = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', phrase)
# general
   phrase = re.sub('@[^\s]+','',phrase)
   phrase = remove_accented_chars(phrase)
   phrase = remove_special_characters(phrase)
   phrase = remove_emoji(phrase)
   return phrase

def remove_accented_chars(text):
  new_text = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
  return new_text

def remove_special_characters(text):
  # define the pattern to keep
  pat = r'[^a-zA-z0-9.,!?/:;\"\'\s]'
  return re.sub(pat, '', text)
```

Applying it to the dataframe column like so:

```
AAVE["sentence"] = AAVE["sentence"].apply(decontracted)
```

['He better hurry amp; come back from playing cards', 'I ordered a new phone', 'lol okay baby \ud83d\ude18\u2764\ud83d\ude0d', 'imma cry']

Above is an example of the text I'm testing on. \ud83d\ude18\u2764\ud83d\ude0d is not removed.

-------------edit------------

Here is the code I am using to load the data that is in a TSV file:

```
AAVE = pd.read_csv('twitteraae_all_aa', sep='\t', on_bad_lines='skip')
columns = ['ID', 'Date', 'Num', 'Location','Num2', 'AA', 'Hispanic', 'Other', 'White']
AAVE.drop(columns, inplace=True, axis=1)
AAVE = AAVE.rename(columns={'Sentence': 'sentence'})
AAVE['label'] = 1

AAVE['sentence'] = AAVE['sentence'][0:391165].astype('string')
AAVE = AAVE.dropna()
AAVE['sentence1'] = AAVE['sentence'].astype('string').apply(decontracted).astype('string')
```

The code will work if I create an array of strings and apply the decontract function, but if I apply it to the dataframe, everything else that I want removed works, but not the emojis.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is functional for removing emojis operating column by column

```
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').str.decode('ascii'))
```

Note that it will also removes all non-English letters and special characters, but if you need to keep them we can edit the code

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply row by row using

```
AAVE["sentence"] = AAVE.apply(lambda row: remove_emoji(row["sentence"]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions work for me:

```
arr = ['He better hurry amp; come back from playing cards', 'I ordered a new phone',
         'lol okay baby \ud83d\ude18\u2764\ud83d\ude0d', 'imma cry']
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": [0, 1, 2, 3], "column2": arr})
```

```
df
   column1                                            column2
0        0  He better hurry amp; come back from playing cards
1        1                              I ordered a new phone
2        2                                lol okay baby \ud83d\ude18❤\ud83d\ude0d
3        3                                           imma cry
```

```
df["column2"] = df["column2"].apply(decontracted)
df
   column1                                            column2
0        0  He better hurry amp; come back from playing cards
1        1                              I ordered a new phone
2        2                                     lol okay baby 
3        3                                           imma cry
```

Could it be an issue with how the text is stored in your dataframe?

Comment: I think you may be right that it is a problem with how the data is being stored in the data frame. Can you look at the updated question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If the emojis are escaped (i.e., have an extra backslash before them), try changing the encoding type in the decode function to 'unicode_escape'.

Comment: If the emojis aren't escaped, what would you suggest??